# About CT secondary winding on toroidal transformer

Tags: transformer

I am done primary winding today of my toroidal core. Attached photo of transformer below. 755 turn of 0.914 mm magnet wire. Core size before winding OD-100mm, ID-60mm, Ht-50mm (M4,CRGO). Sir when I test for secondary voltage I get 2.7 volt on 10 turn of magnet wire. why I get less volt per turn. Because before making the primary winding I done partial test on core, wind 10 turn for secondary, I get 3.2 volt. And I am winding center tap for this transformer of 35-0-35 using dual winding method (2 wire at same time, bifilar.) If I want lower voltage from same winding can it be done? e.g for 25-0-25?

[image: Toroidal Transformer]

Comment: A CT usually has 1 or 2 turns on the primary. Can you explain your question to make it easier to follow? Basic punctuation will help a bit.

Comment: What happens if you apply (say) 1/2 the input voltage with your 10-turn secondary? Maybe it is saturating because  you don't have enough primary turns. Your proposed bifilar winding of a centre-tapped secondary should be practical at that voltage level.

Comment: Ok I am wind primary of toroidal transformer with 755 turn of 0.914mm magnet wire. But before primary winding I test core with sample winding  with old transformer which have 12 volt secondary. so on toroidal core I  have did winded up 37 turn for primary and 20 turn for secondary I got 6.66 volt on out. but after actual wind full 755 turn on primary i test secondary voltage again with 20 turn this time I got 5.5 to 5.7 volt. why volt per turn is droping?

Comment: What voltage did you apply to the 755 primary? 240V or 220V?

Comment: 230 volt  And get 5.6 volt on 20 turn secondary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But before primary winding I test core with sample winding with old
>   transformer which have 12 volt secondary.

With 12 V and a turns ratio of 37:20 you should expect about 6.5 V. You measured 6.66 V and this sounds OK.

> after actual wind full 755 turn on primary i test secondary voltage
>   again with 20 turn this time I got 5.5 to 5.7 volt

755:20 with 5.6 volts on secondary implies a primary voltage of 211 volts.

Maybe you thought you were feeding 240 V but you only have 210 V.

Comment: No sir I tested mains voltage before feeding it was in between 230 to 234 volt

Comment: Then maybe you have miscounted the turns or your turns are not coupled magnetically as well as you expected. Did you have a load on the output?

Comment: but I did series bulb test for primary bulb is fully power off. can i add more turn on primary.

Comment: I don't know what the series bulb test is. Measure the mA taken by the primary when connected to 240 V.

Comment: Series bulb test is give mains supply to primary winding with indusind bulb (who can oprate on mains voltage) in series. If bulb is stay off means turn is ok if bulb is dim on means more  turn required

Comment: Well that's OK as a ball-park test but it doesn't mean you haven't wound too many turns. To do this properly you need to measure the current from 240 V into 755 turns and the current from 12 V into 37 turns. Of course if the transformer is not getting too warm on 240 V just add more turns to the secondary.

Comment: Andy, your calculations seem correct.  I would suspect the following 3 in order, most likely first: Multimeter has error in range scaling (or other measurement error like waveform shape) , core is saturating but bulb test and amount of wire looks good, or turns count on primary inaccurate. Very nice winding job by the way @Sandeep, how did you do it?

Comment: Thanks KalleMp, I did winded with hand with help of may friend.

Comment: Hi Andy aka I wound secondary of this transformer about 50 turn and then   check voltage,it gives 15.3 volt means 0.306 volt per turn. I think it is good v/turn. What's your thought.

Comment: My answer is "me" saying to "you" that I believe you have miscounted the number of primary turns. This follows on from you not understanding why 755:20 only gives 5.6 V from 232 V whereas 12 V into a ratio of 37:20 gives 6.6 V. Asking me what my thoughts are on volts/turn is irrelevant so, my question to you is this: "have you solved the problem of the turns ratio error". I ask this because until this is solved (or understood) there is little point in me commenting further.

Comment: Hello Andy aka Let's start again I wound Primary 755 round for 230volt so 755/230=3.28 turn/volt ok.Than I wound 20 turn for secondary and get 5.7 volt(3.50 turn/volt) after continued winding to 50 turn get 15.3 volt(3.26 turn/volt) than after full winding for secondary 115 turn I got final wanted 36 volt and got with 3.19 turn/volt. I count all turn accurately.so you tell me whats problem. I think when I use all circumference of core turn per volt required less.

Comment: With fewer turns, the magnetic coupling isn't as good as with many turns. With many turns on the secondary there is a greater chance that coupling is improved hence volts per turn rise with more secondary turns.

Comment: thanks Andy aka how to test this transformer current capacity with load.I don't have high watt resistor. is any other method to test transformer maximum current drawn.This transformer have 35-0-35 and 25-0-25 volt out.

Comment: You need a high wattage resistor - If you want to check regulation I don't know of any other way. Anyway, this question is somewhat evolving now so please consider asking a new question about transformer testing or look for a similar question on stack exchange - I'm sure there will be something. If you believe you have got the answer you are looking for please consider up-voting and/or accepting the answer.